# JavaScript equivalent to URLEncoder.encode("String", "UTF-8") of Java

Tags: javascript

I want to encode a string to `UTF-8` in JavaScript. In java we use `URLEncoder.encode("String", "UTF-8")` to achieve this.

I know we can use `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` but it is producing different output `than URLEncoder.encode`

Can anyone please suggest any available JS method that can be used to achieve same output as `URLEncoder.encode`.

**NOTE:**
Due to restrictions I cannot use jQuery.

Comment: Can you give an example where `encodeURIComponent` and `encodeURI` don't work properly?

Comment: Why there was a downvote it is really a very good question i am stuck in this same problem for last 5 days ??

Comment: @Sandeep did you get anything or not ?? please reply must.

Comment: An example where the output of encodeURIComponent and encodeURI don't match the URLEncoder.encode is the space character for example (one outputs `+`, the other two `%20%`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this `javaURLEncode()` function is a spot-on match for Java's `URLEncoder.encode` method, but it might be close to what you're looking for:

```js
function javaURLEncode(str) {
  return encodeURI(str)
    .replace(/%20/g, "+")
    .replace(/!/g, "%21")
    .replace(/'/g, "%27")
    .replace(/\(/g, "%28")
    .replace(/\)/g, "%29")
    .replace(/~/g, "%7E");
}

var testString = "It's ~ (crazy)!";
var jsEscape = escape(testString);
var jsEncodeURI = encodeURI(testString);
var jsEncodeURIComponent = encodeURIComponent(testString);
var javaURLEncoder = javaURLEncode(testString);
alert("Original: " + testString + "\n" +
  "JS escape: " + jsEscape + "\n" +
  "JS encodeURI: " + jsEncodeURI + "\n" +
  "JS encodeURIComponent: " + jsEncodeURIComponent + "\n" +
  "Java URLEncoder.encode: " + javaURLEncoder);
```

Answer (score 0):

found one more character should be replaced
.replace(/\$/g, "%24")